# update react 16.8.3 but ant design icons-react 1.1.2 require icons 1.1.0

Tags: reactjs, antd

I updated reactjs 15 to react 16.8.3.

```
@ant-design/icons-react@1.1.2 requires a peer of @ant-design/icons@~1.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

How can I update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What it means:**

`@ant-design/icons-react@1.1.2` needs `@ant-design/icons-react@1.1.0` to work properly.

We (NPM) won't install it for you (due to reasons mentioned [here](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5)) so install the [peerDependency](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) yourself.

**How to do it (not tested):**

`npm i --save @ant-design/react-icons@1.1.0`, this will install version 1.1.0 alongside version 1.1.2 and the error should resolve itself.